# Password checker not returning true

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

I have written a password checker to check the security of a password. There are three functions to check the security and return the value, **weak**, **medium**, and **strong**. I call the functions here:

```
if check_pass_strength_weak(password):
            print "Weak"
        elif check_pass_strength_medium(password):
            print "Medium"
        elif check_pass_strength_strong(password):
            print "Strong""
```

but strong is never returned. Here is the function.

```
def check_pass_strength_strong(password):
    upper_count = 0
    lower_count = 0
    number_count = 0
    for letter in password:
        if letter == letter.upper():
            upper_count = upper_count + 1
        elif letter == letter.lower():
            lower_count = lower_count + 1
        elif letter.isalpha():
            number_count = number_count + 1

    if upper_count > 0 and lower_count > 0 and number_count > 0:
        return True
```

Comment: you should'nt indent the elif statements

Comment: You didn't provide other methods, but that's probably because your logic has an implication that "password is strong => password is medium" and "password is strong => password is weak". So your first methods also return `true` for strong password, and further conditions are not checked.

Comment: It's possible your medium always returns true. It might be simpler if instead of having 3 functions you have one function that returns the password strength.

Comment: What is returned when you expect the password to be strong?  Nothing, or weak, or medium?

Comment: A strong password is probably also medium

Comment: @AmirAfghani I was originally doing that but omitted that code. Jon's solution seems to have worked. Thanks

Comment: It's probably not relevant to the problem at hand, but the third condition should be `not letter.isalpha()` or `letter.isdigit()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that:

```
'1' == '1'.upper()
```

so the rest of your `elif` never run and `number_count` is never incremented. Flip it around:

```
if letter.isdigit():
    ...
elif ...
```

Or, better, actually use Python's [`str` methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods), and remember to `return False`:

```
def check_pass_strength_strong(password):
    upper_count = 0
    lower_count = 0
    number_count = 0
    for letter in password:
        if letter.isdigit():
            number_count += 1
        elif letter.isupper():
            upper_count += 1
        elif letter.islower():
            lower_count += 1
    if upper_count > 0 and lower_count > 0 and number_count > 0:
        return True
    return False
```

---

In fact, as you're checking multiple levels, you could factor out the counting:

```
def count_char_types(password):
    lower_count = upper_count = number_count = 0
    for letter in password:
        if letter.isdigit():
            number_count += 1
        elif letter.isupper():
            upper_count += 1
        elif letter.islower():
            lower_count += 1
    return lower_count, upper_count, number_count
```

then implement e.g.

```
def check_pass_strength_strong(password):
    l, u, n = count_char_types(password)
    return l > 0 and u > 0 and n > 0
```

and consider adding a `symbol_count`!

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs two fixes. First, as noted by [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23983762/2642204), `'1' == '1'.upper()` so you don't count the numbers. You need to verify this first:

```
if letter.isdigit():
    #...
elif #upper/lower conditions
```

And you probably want to reverse your conditions for password strength:

```
if check_pass_strength_strong(password):
    print "Strong"
elif check_pass_strength_medium(password):
    print "Mediu"
elif check_pass_strength_weak(password):
    print "Weak"
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using regex for checking digit/uppercase/lowercase character?

e.g.:

```
def check_pass_strength_strong(password):
    return all((re.findall(r'[A-Z]', password),
                re.findall(r'[a-z]', password),
                re.findall(r'[0-9]', password)))
```